# Media storage android

Tags: android, kotlin, local-storage, mediastore

Android 10 or +

I would like to save recorder audio in storage but I get:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Primary directory Documents not allowed for content://media/external/audio/media; allowed directories are [Alarms, Music, Notifications, Podcasts, Ringtones]

My code is

```
mRecorder = MediaRecorder() // TODO: Get media recorder
with(mRecorder!!) {
    setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
    setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP)
    setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
}

val values = ContentValues().apply {
    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "${System.currentTimeMillis().days}")
    put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg")
    put(
        MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,
        "${Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS}/mch/"
    )
}

val resolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
val uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri("external"), values)
```

I think the problem is resolver.insert

I change

```
resolver.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri("external"), values)
```

to

```
resolver.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
```

And still crashing

Comment: Please, post the logcat with the crash.

Comment: The error message you provided indicates that you are trying to save the recorded audio file in a directory that is not allowed by the `MediaStore`. The `MediaStore` is a content provider that allows you to access media files, such as audio, images, and videos, on the device

Comment: Please change `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS` to `Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC` and try again